# Fresh Magento 2 installation no CSS

Tags: magento2, css

I have successfully installed a fresh Magento 2 instance on my mac however none of the CSS is loading. Could someone advise of a fix?

The following folders dont exist 
/pub/static/frontend/
/pub/static/adminhtml/

However looking at the htaccess rules it seems they shouldnt as it gets routed to static.php is that correct?

Comment: You run bin/magento setup:static-content-deploy in directory install and reload page

Comment: If I try to run that it states 

`-bash: bin/magento: Permission denied`

Then if I run

`find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento`


I get the following:
`chmod: bin/magento: No such file or directory`

Comment: Okay got it to run if I put in `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` note the :
However the issue still remains even though the CSS file now exists

Comment: could you please confirm what error you see in browsers console? and is it 404 or 403? have you tried to delete `var/*` and restart apache?

Comment: Ah noticed /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB/mage/calendar.css is the css link however the folder structure i have /pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css note the US and not GB. How do I get the en_GB?

Comment: In my case i have error 403.

Comment: @Goose84: Maybe you should try to change mage_core_config_data (e.g. with phpmyadmin) from en_GB to en_US

I am not sure if there is a en_GB localisation.

Comment: if you have 403 then permissions are wrong. files must be owned by php user and readable by apache user.

Comment: changing the  mage_core_config_data (e.g. with phpmyadmin) from en_GB to en_US didnt work :-(

Answer (score 2):

run command as owner of magento files from magento root folder:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

if you run it as root you will have to change user:

```
su - {user}
```

or switch user and run command in one line:

```
su - {user} /usr/bin/php -c bin/magento en_GB
```

then run `chown` command so every file will be properly owned:

```
chown -R {user}:{group} *
```

if you get error from static files deployment , you will have to fix them, until you will get success message.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as per my comments above I have done this however its pulled the wrong locale for the css its pulling en_US and not en_GB. Any advice on how to fix would be great

Comment: Did you ever work out why it is pulling en_US instead of GB - I am getting exactly the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Deploy content by using the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Then Set the writable permissions to var, pub/static and pub/media directories. you can use the command:

```
 chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static pub/media
```